# demarcating conversations with Wicket-CDI

Tags: java, cdi, jboss-weld, wicket-1.5

I'm using [Wicket-CDI](https://github.com/42Lines/wicket-cdi) to integrate CDI with Wicket. I have a multi-page "wizard" flow, in which the user completes various forms using a bean that's marked with `@ConversationScoped`.

The flow works fine, but I can't figure out how to "reset" the bean when I explicitly end the conversation. I have a "start over" link that does:

```
public void onClick() {
    conversation.end();
    setResponsePage(WizardFlowPage1.class);
}
```

I've verified that my page constructor is called and that the conversation gets a new cid, but the conversational bean that gets injected is the same instance as the previous flow (with all the fields retaining their previous values).

A simple fix is to add a `reset()` method to the bean and reset the fields, but this seems like a hack (and prone to error if I later add a new field).

How can I convince CDI/Weld to create a new instance of the conversational bean when the conversation is ended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my conversation bean had some fields that were missing getters & setters. Wicket's [PropertyModel](http://armhold.com/apidocs/wicket-core/index.html?org/apache/wicket/model/PropertyModel.html) allows you to get away with this as a convenience.

Adding the getters & setters made it conform to [JavaBean conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans), and allowed CDI to properly do its thing.